# can't get PG connection going in PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I am unable to connect to my database. Sure I'm just missing something simple:

```
$host = "localhost";
$port = "5432";
$db_name = 'db';
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$db_name; host=$host", $username, $password );

$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE , PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$sth = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM   test1
    WHERE  id = :id
    ");

$sth->bindValue(':id', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
```

I get the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "test1" does not
>   exist LINE 3: FROM test1 ^' in ...[url]... address Stack trace: #0 ...[url]... PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in ...[url]

Thanks!

Comment: Does table `test1` exist?

Comment: **Read The Error Message** Seems to me you are getting connected just fine if it can tell you that your table doesn't exist.

Comment: @tadman yeah, it does.

Comment: @adear11 Yeah, but I can see it in phpPgAdmin

Comment: Are you sure that your table name is `db`?

Comment: @Andrew yeah, I just changed those to simple values for the SO post. Thanks

Comment: maybe try adding `charset=utf8` to your $dbh

Comment: Also, for PostgreSQL, the table names are case sensitive so make sure your table name matches exactly. As I said, looks like you are getting connected because the query is running. Can you post the CREATE TABLE statement for the table in question?

Comment: @Andrew How would that look? is there a set charset method?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$port = '5432';
$db_name = 'db';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

$dbh = new PDO('pgsql:port=' . $port . ';host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db_name . ';charset=utf8', '' . $username . '', '' . $password . '');
```

Comment: That did not work sadly. Removing this line `dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE , PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );` prevented my error. However,  I now am getting this echoed `array(0) { }` from my `var_dump($result);` Thanks for helping

Comment: changing error modes isn't going to help. all you've done is stuffed your fingers in your ears and started changing "la la la la la". fix the **PROBLEM** and stop shooting the messenger.

Comment: @MarcB Easy there. I didn't know it was preventing me from seeing all errors. I was just observing that the lack of that particular line made that particular error not be reported anymore. I thought that could be useful in determining exactly what the error is about.

Comment: Again, can you post the CREATE TABLE for the table in question?

Answer (score 0):

1. try using this DSN Format: "pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=db;user=user;password=pass".
2. check that your user has all the privileges it needs on postgresql to access the schema, DB and that table. "grant select on table test1 TO user" should give you access for that table.

Comment: Deleted and replaced the table. Made sure the user had all privileges set up on both database and table. No luck with your DSN Format